# Excel Formula - Cell equals contents of another cell but display blank if the cell was empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I often have several tabs on my spreadsheets but then have a main page collating data.

I use the easy formula cell "insert cell" equals another cell "insert cell".
If the original cell was empty, it returns a zero.

How do I avoid this? I'm using Excel 2016.

I have included a small image as an example where it creates a zero because the cell it copied from was blank.

[image: Excel spreadsheet showing zeroes instead of blanks]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ISBLANK function e.g.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(JAN!A2),"",JAN!A2)
```

Comment: Thank you @robert - This is exactly the formula I was looking for but couldnt work out where to put what in the formula! Much appreciated